# How can I get a fixed footer like facebook application design

Tags: css

How can I build a fixed footer like facebook application design? Examples with css appreciated.

Duplicate of [Facebook like status div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506835/facebook-like-status-div)

Comment: Some people may not have a huge command of the english language. English is a little ambiguous, and for non-native speakers, it's easy to sound demanding.

Comment: This has been asked here before.  Do a search next time...

Answer (score 7):

One way is given [here](http://sunblu.sh/2008/09/pin-your-footers-with-css/):

In HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

In CSS:

```
#container {
  position:absolute;
  min-height:100%;
}

#content {
  margin-bottom:100px; /* same as footer height */
}

#footer {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  height:100px; /* same as content margin-bottom */
}
```

**Edit:** That link was based on [this](http://boagworld.com/technology/fixed_footers_without_javascri/) which has some exceptions

Answer (score 3):

Facebook's footer stays in place as you scroll. To accomplish this, you'll need HTML like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="content">
    [content]
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    [footer]
  </div>
</body>
```

and CSS like this:

```
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f00;
}
```

The CSS `position: fixed` instructs the browser to keep this element's position fixed, regardless of scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

I have found CSS Play a really helpful site.

http://www.cssplay.co.uk/

More specifically, http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/, for layouts.

Answer (score 0):

More examples at [CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/).

Edit: [Another example](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) with *slightly* cleaner CSS