# Stuck on sticky footer CSS issue

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I know there are several other questions about the sticky footer, but none have seemed to help me get to a solution for my problem. Here is the template in question:

http://blog.campquiet.com/stack/

Basically I would like the background with the transparent side bars to extend to the bottom of the browser window. The footer (copyright info) should always be at the bottom of the screen as well, even if there isn't enough content to push it that far).

Any suggestions??

**Update**
Maybe I wasn't as clear as I needed to be. Basically I'm trying to accomplish what is seen here: hxxp://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

I haven't been able to get that working in my template.

Comment: You mean a fixed footer like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673386/how-can-i-get-a-fixed-footer-like-facebook-application-design

Comment: Not a fixed footer - I don't want the footer to overlap content. I want it to be pinned to the bottom of the window, or pushed lower if content fills up.

Comment: This looks as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224838/stuck-on-sticky-footer-css-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the body and outer container to 100% height. This answer may help you: [CSS 100% height with padding/margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485827/css-100-height-with-padding-margin)

Comment: I added the 100% height to the container div. body and html already had it. Still have the problem! I've been going back and forth between the sticky footer methods, so I may have removed some of the necessary code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I understand what you're asking, but to keep the footer always at the bottom, perhaps try something like this

```
#footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0; /* Keeps the footer glued to the bottom of the page */
    z-index: 9999; /* Keeps the footer on top of all other elements */
}
```

For the background, try to apply the CSS to the `body` tag?

```
body{
    background: url(assets/images/bg_clouds.jpg) fixed 0 0;
}
```

You can apply extra settings for the background (like position & repeat) to get it to look like it is currently. Anyway, if this doesn't answer your question, please help me out with a more detailed explanation of your question.

Hope that helps.

### **UPDATE**

I played around with Firebug to edit your CSS. I think if you get rid of the background css under `html, body {}` and add this to your `body {}`

```
body {
   background: url("assets/images/bg_clouds.jpg") repeat-x fixed 0 0 #F0F4F7;
}
```

... it will keep the background static even if you scroll. It will always be there. Make sure you have `fixed` instead of `scroll`

Comment: I think my question may have led you astray. Please see my update for what I'm trying to accomplish. The clouds background is correct, I'm trying to get the footer to work correctly and have the content area expand to fit the browser window, even if there isn't content to push it down.

Comment: Well... did you try applying what the site talks about? Did you look at the CSS for the sticky footer?

Comment: Yep - I tried implementing the CSS sticky footer, but it wasn't working correctly. I think it has to do with multiple container divs, but I'm uncertain. I'm stumped as to how to get this working, which is why I'm here:)

Comment: I still don't understand what your problem is. Do you want the footer to ALWAYS be on the bottom, no matter if there is a lot or a little content and no matter whether you're scrolling the page? or do you want the footer to be on the bottom only when the content is little... like if the 3 "Header" columns weren't there?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - the second case is what I'm looking for. Say the 3 header elements weren't there. I still want there to be white background and the footer at the bottom of the window.

Comment: OHH ok... that makes sense. I'll fiddle around with it and post back if I find a solution. Sorry for misunderstanding you.

Comment: No worries:) Thank you for your help. I've been trying to get it working all day and now I'm just getting frustrated with each try. Here's another example of it working: hxxp://boagworld.com/demos/FixedFooter/

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out how to fix this... sorry... it is difficult w/o the source code. I would recommend you restructuring your code without any of the background images so that it works the way you want it... then go in and add the images and make it work with the images. Sorry :/